# "mayBeMempty" function for a Semigroup

Tags: haskell, typeclass, monoids, semigroup

The following function -

```
mayBeMempty :: (Eq a, Semigroup a) => a -> a -> Bool
mayBeMempty candidate ref = candidate <> ref == ref
```

Is a (less efficient) generalization of `Data.Set.isSubSetOf`. It checks if the first argument is "contained" in the second one and always returns `True` when the first argument is `mempty` (when it returns `False` it is known to not be `mempty`).

Does anyone know if this function or concept already exist under some name or even an existing type-class (in which case it would not be less efficient than `isSubSetOf`)?

Comment: I wonder if what you really want is semigroup with subtraction of some kind, or the cancellation property... that is with a different class maybe you could write an implementation that is more interesting, e.g. maybe it might be `isSubSequenxeOf` on lists as sequences.

Comment: @assembly.jc: I'm looking for a function that would do the same as `isSubSetOf` when instantiated for `Set a`, and in general would always do something equivalent to `mayBeMempty` defined above but efficiently (not necessarily using `<>` and `==`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PartialOrd`'s [`leq`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.0/lattices-1.7.1.1/Algebra-PartialOrd.html#v:leq) is what I was looking for.

IIUC, a difference is that it is not designed to fit the rules as I described for `Semigroup`, but instead it's designed to work in this manner with `Lattice` which is defined in the same package, which is similar to a semigroup in some ways but better fits things like sets where merging something with itself results in itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have searched with Hoogle and think there is no pre-implemented version of this.

I don't really see how it could be made more efficient, TBH.

Comment: It could be made more efficient if there was a class for this method. Then `Set a`'s instance would be `isSubSetOf`.

Comment: I've also searched with Hoogle before asking on SO and didn't find anything.

After thinking more about this and concluding the the term for it is "partial order" I've now found both https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.0/lattices-1.7.1.1/Algebra-PartialOrd.html and the `partial-order` package on Hackage